# Why do I get undefined method error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I get this error

> undefined method `created_at' for #ActiveRecord::Relation:0x0000001c3f57e8

**controller**

```
    @user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
    @post = @user.comment_threads

    if @post
        last_time = @post.created_at
        if Time.now - last_time <= 0.5.minute
            redirect_to messages_received_path 
            flash[:notice] = "You cannot spam!"   
            return
        end
    end
```

Comment: Because `@post` is a collection of model instances, not a single instance. `@user.comment_threads` must return a collection (relation) not a single record

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because this line `@post = @user.comment_threads` returns an object of `ActiveRecord::Relation` to you. Better put a `.last` or `.first` on the end of that sentence, so you can have a single `Post` object.

Answer (score 2):

`@post = @user.comment_threads` returns you an array of the post object. So `created_at` is attempted on the array as a whole and not on any `post` object.

This should help.

```
if @post
        last_time = @post.last.created_at
        if Time.now - last_time <= 0.5.minute
            redirect_to messages_received_path 
            flash[:notice] = "You cannot spam!"   
            return
        end
    end
```